# Back button is only updating url not the page in a angular application exported as custom-element

Tags: angular, back-button, angular-router, html5-history, popstate

**CONTEXT**: I have built the Tour Of Heroes Application and exported that as a custom-element named app-element. I deployed it on the local server.

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>Custom Element Example</title>
    <base href="/">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundled.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <app-element></app-element>  
</body>
```

**Problem**: When navigate using the buttons present in the application, it works perfectly fine. But When I use the browser's back button for navigating back, it only updates the URL, not the page.

So I decided to detect the event and then render the page fetching the browser's URL.

```
constructor(private router:Router, private location:PlatformLocation){
    location.onPopState((e)=>{
      console.log(location.href);
      this.router.navigate([/** fetch route from location.href */]);
    })
  };
```

This is creating a new problem. It does not allow us to press the browser's forward button now because when we navigate to a URL using the router.navigate method, URL becomes the new top of the browser's history.

Is there any way such that I can render the page while pressing the back button and still able to go forward?

**NOTE** : none of above problem happens when I deploy the application directly without exporting it as a custom-element.